# What is this emphasis "did"?

Tags: grammar

> And he would fain have filled his belly with the husks that the swine **did** eat: and no man gave unto him.

Is this archaic?
I see many instances of this usage where simple verbs would be enough in Shakespeare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you eliminate the did, the 'eat' has to become 'ate' to reflect the past tense.

Yes, I assume this to be from the James l (Authorised Version), which is written in early 17th century English.

It is archaic but, as with so much of the AV in my view, this is an example of its superior poetry to some of the modern translations.

Comment: I suppose people's views on the worth of a Bible version are dependent on whether they see it primarily as an end in itself or a means to an end.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  A lecture I attended, given by a historian of the AV, was immensely interesting in highlighting the influence of 17th-century Royalist politics in the translation. For example there are countless references to kingship, and 'kingliness'. 'Good' kings abound in its pages. Yet there is not a single instance,  I feel sure she said, of the use of the word 'tyrant' or 'tyrannical'. in the entire text.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed archaic;

> did eat

would nowadays be

> ate

Further awesome archaisms include 'would fain,' meaning 'would gladly,' and the construction 'no man gave unto him,' instead of, 'no one gave him anything.'

Comment: I did not eat much but what I did eat made me sick.

Comment: I don’t understand why this answer was downvoted: it is very accurate. (Except perhaps for the word _anachronisms_. When the text quoted was written, they weren’t out of time, so technically I guess they’re not anachronisms.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was torn between anachronisms and atavisms, feeling that something atavistic is far in the past, whereas this is only recently past. On looking up the definition of anachronism, there are two definitions; one close to my usage, and one close to yours. Example relevant to my usage: [the town is a throwback to medieval times, an anachronism that has survived the passing years](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anachronism)

Comment: That example makes sense because the context of the town is _now_, when it does seem out of time. But the context of these words is a text written in a time when the words were normal, that’s why I think _anachronism_ sounds odd. I would simply call them _archaisms_, which doesn’t imply that they are ill-fitted for the present, but simply that they are old-fashioned according to current times.

Comment: @mplungjan indeed, but I think that the full form of that sentence would be 'I did not eat much but that which I did eat made me sick' which is a slightly different usage of the construction.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that is the word I wanted but somehow didn't find! I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Like a lot of people I learned the word *anachronism* from the example in Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar* where the clock strikes. Whilst there are many *archaisms* in Shakespeare, that is a valid example of an 'anachronism*; since whilst they had striking clocks in the days of Shakespeare, they did not have them in ancient Rome.

Comment: @WS2 And importing the notion of anachronism into reading *JC* is another anachronism, since a concern for 'chronism'  in fiction doesn't really arise until Scott. :)

Comment: @StoneyB But surely 'anachronisms' existed, before the word was coined; in the same way that the planet Pluto was there before it was spotted through a telescope in the 1920s.

Comment: 'Planet' Pluto has been in a state of existential flux for most of its known lifetime, having been added to then removed from the category multiple times, as I recall.